# Leaving non-harmful questions open?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Some questions are quite obviously off topic ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523498/vim-c-qt-c-development-powerful-plugins) that I think is both too broad and primarily opinion-based), but still appear to work. They get decent answers and the OP is helped.

I think that when reviewing close votes, a "don't-fix-what-aint-broken"-mentality should be used. Even if a question is off-topic according to one or more close reasons, I don't think it should be closed if it appears to work on the site.

What are the guidelines on this kind of border cases? Can I leave them open? Or should anything that fits any close reason be ruthlessly closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with leaving such questions open is that they then get used by others as justification for asking their really bad too broad or opinion based question. We get accused of having double standards and being "nasty to newbies" and it makes our job of keeping the site a place where experts want to answer harder.

It's far better to be consistent and apply the same criteria to all questions regardless of whether they've been answered or not.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's sad that the rules have to be that strictly enforced.

Comment: @AndersAbel - If people didn't take liberties then *perhaps* we could be a bit more liberal, but phrases like "thin end of the wedge" spring to mind.